# GraphQL: Generate static documentation from SDL file

Tags: node.js, graphql

The NPM library [graphql-docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-docs) will statically generate GraphQL API documentation from a successful schema introspection call against the API server.

I need to similarly generate GraphQL API documentation, but based on an [SDL](http://graphql.org/learn/schema/) file rather than from an introspection call.

I know I can generate a server stub from my SDL at built time and introspect against that, but this seems like overkill.

Is there a library or a tool-chain, in any language, that makes generating docs from an SDL file simple?

Comment: FWIW, if you do end up going with graphql-docs, I've got a fork that offers a more complete solution here: https://github.com/danielrearden/graphql-docs

Comment: Can we add sample query and mutation req & resp to the generated files usinggraphql-docs? Recently I installed and used graphql-docs and can generate files but the files were only having the query,mutation names and the description of the object attributes etc. I need to add some sample queries and responses as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've messed around with [graphdoc](https://github.com/2fd/graphdoc) before, which can generate static documentation from an SDL file, JSON or even graphql-tools' `executableSchema`. I don't think there's a lot of other tools out there, since most teams just rely on [GraphiQL](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql) or [GraphQL Playground](https://github.com/graphcool/graphql-playground) for their documentation needs.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend https://github.com/2fd/graphdoc to generate a static doc of a GraphQL endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

There are now 2 more recent open source projects to do that.

- [Magidoc](https://github.com/magidoc-org/magidoc)
- [SpectaQL](https://github.com/anvilco/spectaql)

Both support creating static docs from SDL files or introspection query.